# How to Connect to SQL Azure Using ADO.net?

Tags: c#, azure, ado.net, azure-sql-database

I'm writing a C# application that needs to be able to query and update an Azure SQL database. I've looked into ADO.NET, which appears to be a great library for querying SQL databases without just writing the queries as string literals.

Before I invest too much time into learning this library I want to make sure that I can connect it to Azure successfully. I found [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/msdn-article-how-to-connect-to-sql-azure-using-ado-net/) which appears to have at one point contained a tutorial for doing exactly that, but doesn't exist anymore. Can anyone confirm that ADO.NET can be used with Azure SQL?

Comment: You should invest more time into learning some essential .NET concepts such as data access. You'll find the answer pretty quick if you do.

Comment: One can query and update Azure SQL Database from ADO.NET exactly as one would an on-prem instance. So the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: If my reply is helpful to you, please mark it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Of course we can.

ADO.NET can be used with Azure SQL, we can use ADO.NET to operate Azure SQL just like we operate SQL Server. But there are some differences between Azure SQL Db and SQL Server, we can refer to: [Feature comparison: Azure SQL Database versus SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-features)

We can also use `Linq to SQL` to operate SQL Azure for some simple operations because it is more convenient to operate our database. More information we can refer to: [LINQ to SQL: .NET Language-Integrated Query for Relational Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score -1):

You can and you can find the connection string to use in the Azure Portal. Here's a guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet-visual-studio